# Tomcat incur dangling connections when client disconnect

Tags: java, tomcat8, connector

I am using Tomcat instance that serves videos approx. 400 MB in size. I wrote a simple test case to create 500 threads to download a video file from tomcat server

```
public void startTestCase(){
    //URLDownload class opens a connection to given URL and read the input stream 
    ArrayList<Thread> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 500; i > 0; i--){
        list.add(new Thread(new URLDownloader(url)));
    }
    int t = 0;
    for (Thread thread : list) {
        System.out.println(t++);
        thread.start();
    }

    for (Thread thread : list) {
        try {
            System.out.println(t--);
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**My test procedure:**

1. I ran above code for few minutes on Eclipse. Code starts to download 500 concurrent files pointed to by url input to URLDownloader
2. Then I presses "Terminate" to shutdown all threads at once which emulate a scenario where user watch a video for few minutes and close the browser because he was bored with it.

Observed on tomcat instance that runs on Eclipse:

1. I have almost all 500 connection hanged on tomcat, I can see it from Eclise Debug view as "Daemon Thread [http-nio-8080-exec-949] (Running)".
2. After some time passed I see all of them at once start to terminate and disapeader from Eclipse Debug view.

**stack of a dangling thread:**

```
Daemon Thread [http-nio-8080-exec-1049] (Suspended) 
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) line: 215   
AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) line: 2078  
TaskQueue(LinkedBlockingQueue<E>).poll(long, TimeUnit) line: 467    
TaskQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit) line: 85 
TaskQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit) line: 31 
ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).getTask() line: 1066 
ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1127  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617   
TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() line: 61  
TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 745
```

Note:

One time which I can not seem to reproduce again, all of the threads were suspended on following line of code I have on my file serving servlet

```
 while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, read); // <-- at this point 
    numberOfBytesRead += read;
    rd.numberOfKBSent = numberOfBytesRead;
    sleep(15);
}
```

**My tomcat connector setting on server.xml**

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="5000" maxConnections="5000" maxThreads="5000" acceptorThreadCount="8"/>
```

I prepared it using http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

My think I am missing some important parameter from above line. Is there a way to kill the thread as soon as user disconnect the download? I need to have high availability to serve as many concurrent users as possible, if all disconnected threads dangle around then my maxThreads will runout and new users cannot connect to the server.

**Server setup:**
1 Gbps local area connection
4 Core, 8 HT processor 
Tomcat 8 instance runs on Eclipse Mars Debug mode
HTTP connector details listed above under tomcat connector settings

**URLDownload class:**

```
class URLDownloader implements Runnable {
    String url;
    public URLDownloader(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int i = 0;
            while((i= in.read(b)) != -1){

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

=======Edited to add stack trace of a thread stuck at output.write(buffer,0,read); =======

```
Daemon Thread [http-nio-8080-exec-2040] (Suspended) 
owns: InternalNioOutputBuffer  (id=32497)   
owns: NioChannel  (id=32498)    
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) line: 215   
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) line: 1037  
CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).tryAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) line: 1328 
CountDownLatch.await(long, TimeUnit) line: 277  
NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitLatch(CountDownLatch, long, TimeUnit) line: 1375 
NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitWriteLatch(long, TimeUnit) line: 1378    
NioBlockingSelector.write(ByteBuffer, NioChannel, long) line: 114   
NioSelectorPool.write(ByteBuffer, NioChannel, Selector, long, boolean) line: 173    
InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(ByteBuffer, boolean, boolean) line: 139   
InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(byte[], int, int) line: 197 
InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer, byte[], int, int) line: 41  
InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(ByteChunk, Response) line: 320   
IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(ByteChunk, Response) line: 84  
InternalNioOutputBuffer(AbstractOutputBuffer<S>).doWrite(ByteChunk, Response) line: 256 
Response.doWrite(ByteChunk) line: 503   
OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(byte[], int, int) line: 388 
ByteChunk.append(byte[], int, int) line: 315    
OutputBuffer.writeBytes(byte[], int, int) line: 418 
OutputBuffer.write(byte[], int, int) line: 406  
CoyoteOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: 97 
VideoStream.copy(RandomAccessFile, OutputStream, long, long, VideoStream$RequestData) line: 502 <-- this is where it dangle
VideoStream.processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean, VideoStream$RequestData) line: 402 
VideoStream.doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 171    
VideoStream(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 622 
VideoStream(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 729 
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 291  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206  
WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 52    
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 239  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206  
StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 219    
StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 106    
NonLoginAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 502    
StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 142   
ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 79 
AccessLogValve(AbstractAccessLogValve).invoke(Request, Response) line: 610  
StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 88  
CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 518  
Http11NioProcessor(AbstractHttp11Processor<S>).process(SocketWrapper<S>) line: 1091 
Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler(AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler<S,P>).process(SocketWrapper<S>, SocketStatus) line: 668    
Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(SocketWrapper<NioChannel>, SocketStatus) line: 223    
NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(SelectionKey, NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment) line: 1517   
NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() line: 1474    
ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1142  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 617   
TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() line: 61  
TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 745
```

VideoStream servlet is the name of my servlet that serves video files

Comment: (1) Where is the `URLDownloader` class? (2) Why do you have a file downloading servlet? Tomcat can serve static content by default. (3) Why does your servlet sleep for 15ms after every read? (4) Why, given that it does sleep after every read, are you surprised that the servlet takes longer than expected to cease serving? (5) Are you aware that a connection timeout is distinct from a read timeout?

Comment: 1. Added URLDownload class to the post
2. I use a servlet since I want to log how much bandwidth each user consumes. i.e I log number of bytes i wrote to output stream
3. I sleep 15 ms to control Bandwidth for a single user. i.e I write 25kb every 15 ms which comes up to around 9mbps
4. I am okay with taking longer as long as one not consuming all of the bandwidth
5. I dont understand the question properly. So you saying connection stays alive until my file read time out expires. I dont get it.. explanation please..

Comment: See https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/timeouts.html - inspect **socket_timeout**. Maybe the valve **StuckThreadDetectionValve** might be of interest. _(I am not much using Tomcat these days.)_